# How do I use UltraVNC?

Tags: 11.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I'd like to be able to upload files like a Windows version of VNC's. How can I upload files using VNC? I have tried tigerVNC, default VNC, but with none can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look a [NoMachine NX](http://www.nomachine.com/select-package.php?os=linux&id=1). Not VNC, but very robust and excellent performance.